# Jquery mobile select list not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This is getting a bit crazy, i have two divs in my page and two slect lists in each div.
in first div the code is working as expected but in second div it's not.i have written fallowing code in both div-

```
 <select onchange="populateStateSelectBox('','ADDR_SHIP_COUNTRY','ADDR_SHIP_STATE');" name="ADDR_SHIP_COUNTRY" id="ADDR_SHIP_COUNTRY" data-native-menu="false" data-theme="c">
            <option value="">Country</option> 

              <option value="zx">'''' </option>

              <option value="af">Afghanistan </option>

              <option value="hh">Aftab </option>

              <option value="ar">Aire </option>
    </select>
```

AS i read this line in jquery docs-**To use custom menus on a specific select, just add the data-native-menu="false" attribute**
Here is reference [Jquery Select List](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html)
i did the same, but it's working in first div but doesn't working in second div..
Any one having any idea why it's happening like that, i am trying to resolve since last 5 hrs, but no luck.. :(
Please some one suggest me where i am wrong.

I want this out put...http://jsfiddle.net/XbbdU/3/

**EDTIT-
Code related to second list-**

```
 <b>Country *:</b> 
        <select data-theme="c" data-native-menu="false" id="<%=WebKeys.ADDR_SHIP_COUNTRY%>"  name="<%=WebKeys.ADDR_SHIP_COUNTRY%>"  onchange="populateStateSelectBox('','<%=WebKeys.ADDR_SHIP_COUNTRY%>','<%=WebKeys.ADDR_SHIP_STATE%>');" >
        <option value ="">Country</option> 
         <%for(int i=0; i<countryBean.length ;i++){
            CountryBean country = countryBean[i];%>
          <option value ="<%=country.getCountryCode()%>" <%if(country.getCountryCode().equals(shippingAddress.getCountry())){%> selected <%}%> ><%= country.getCountry()%> </option>
         <%}%>
        </select>
```

On Click of this list i am populating the content of second list..as you can see i have called a function on onchange event..

Comment: id's are different in each div..i have just given mark up which i am using in all div's.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/XbbdU/65/

Comment: yes..but it's not happening in my page..actually on page load only select list of first div is visible and rest two or hidden, on click of a button i am displaying another two...so this can be reason..?????i am very confused..please help me out

Comment: Can you either jsfiddle your whole code or post a link?

Comment: i can't post a link because it's on dev server..but try to produce in jsfiddle

Comment: Are you creating the second list programmatically?.If so please post the relevant code too..

Comment: yes..i am...please find edit in my question

Comment: The second select doesnt have an ID assigned to it at all

Comment: @rickyduck- We don't need id's for this..jquery mobile framework seraches for select tag and if found customised it if data-native-menu="false" attribute is there..and in that i have just missed to type the id..id is there..

Answer (score 1):

Try triggering a create in the second div-probably as the last line in your `populateStateSelectBox` method.

Something like this:

```
$("#div2").trigger('create');//div2 is the id of the div enclosing second select
```

Comment: what it will do..that `create`?

Comment: It will make sure that jquery mobile styles are getting applied properly on the new select you are creating.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two selects with the same ID on a page. Give each one a unique ID. I have assumed this answer because you say "it doesn't work in the second div"... if you want further help, please post some more mark up (eg the select in the second div).

Comment: id's are different in each div..i have just given mark up which i am using in all div's.